# Can i load tga file in picturebox?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

Is it possible to load *.tga file in picturebox?
Actually i need to create a container that can display pictures and also video clips, but first i was looking for something to load TGA files.

Comment: In case this is still useful to someone, I've created a lightweight library in pure C# for loading TGA images (along with some other formats): https://github.com/dmitrybrant/imageformats/tree/master/ImageFormats

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure you can! Look at [TargaImage](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31702/NET-Targa-Image-Reader).

Alternatively, you could look at [DevIL](http://www.mastropaolo.com/devildotnet/) but that might be a bit of an overkill depending on your situation.

Comment: While accurate and written in a small amount of code, TargaImage is by no means fast.

Comment: You're right, I would have recommended DeviIL but it's probably overkill unless the OP's use justifies it. I'll add that as an option.

Answer (score 6):

By Default, TGA files are not readble by .NET as no internal TGA file handler is there in the Framework...

But If External Class Libraries are OK,

You can use [`The .NET Targa Image Reader`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31702/NET-Targa-Image-Reader) from `CodeProject` to read TGA image in a PictureBox...

You will find some example codes at the Linked Page to load TGA images in normal PictureBoxes...

And Dont forget to check the comments there, there is a [`Simple But Necessary Fix`](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/4209395/Re-Great-work-Simple-fix-needed.aspx) mentioned there...